# Retrieved data from database and store it in select tag in php

Tags: php

I'm working on update user account and my problem is how do i get the value of user type and store it in a combobox or select tag. Here's my code:

```
<select class="form-control" name="user_type" required>
   <option value=''>Select Type</option>
      <?php
        $query = "SELECT * FROM user_types";
        $result = mysqli_query($connections, $query);
        while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
          $db_id = $rows["user_type_id"];
          $db_desc = $rows["description"];

          echo "<option value='$db_id'>$db_desc</option>";
       }
      ?>
</select>
```

From here i can get all of the user type in my database. Here's my user_types table.

[image]

And my users table

[image]

My question is how do i get the id and value of the user type based on users table and put that in select tag

[image]

Here's i can't get the value of user type

Comment: you will need a `LEFT JOIN` for that

Comment: and how do i put the result in combobox?

Comment: something like `"SELECT user.user_id, user_types.user_type_id, user_types.description from users LEFT JOIN user_types on users.user_type_id=user_types.user_type_id"`

Comment: OR do you only want the user_types the current user has??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking that you are working on editing users in your system.  You would like to have the ability to change their User Type by allowing the logged in person to choose from a select box.

I suggest the following:

First you will need to read your User Types table into an array.  The array keys need to be the user_type_id and the value needs to be the description.

When you would show the user_type_id, instead show this new array value for that index.

When you are displaying this field for editing, do exactly like your code in the original question but also denote the option as "selected" if it matches the user type of the user that you are editing.

```
<?php 
//$user will have all the data for the user you are editing
$query = "SELECT * FROM user_types";
$result = mysqli_query($connections, $query);
$user_types = array();
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $db_id = $rows["user_type_id"];
  $db_desc = $rows["description"];
  $user_types[$db_id] = $db_desc;
}


?>
<select class="form-control" name="user_type" required>
   <option value=''>Select Type</option>
      <?php

        foreach($user_types as $id => $desc){
          if ($user['user_type_id'] == $id){
            echo "<option selected='selected' value='$id'>$desc</option>";
          }else{
            echo "<option value='$id'>$desc</option>";
          }
       }
      ?>
</select>
```

When you handle the form being submitted, the value in $_POST['user_type'] will be the user_type_id corresponding to the selected user type.

Comment: Can you please provide a code for that? Thank you sir

Comment: @YadYoung This would be quite a lot of code to write from scratch, and SO isn't  a coding service.

Comment: Your code was very close to what you needed, you just needed to add in "selected" so that the default user type is showing in the HTML form.  It's not strictly necessary to store the User types in an array but this way you can access them later in the code without hitting the database a second time.

Comment: @YadYoung When you start this form, you should have done a database query to get the user data to initially populate your edit form.  I suggest storing that data in an array called $user, much like I stored the data from the user_types query.

Comment: @YadYoung You should know the user_id since someone clicked a user's edit link to get to this page.  The id is probably in $_GET or $_POST.  You will at some point need to "Select * from users where user_id = 'that_id';"  Then read that user data into an array probably named $user.  When you are creating your edit form, set the default value of the input textboxes to be the data you read from that user table query.